# extract week columns from date in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe that has columns like these:

```
Date          earnings    workingday   length_week  first_wday_week last_wdayweek            

01.01.2000    10000              1              1                            
02.01.2000    0                  0              1                                 
03.01.2000    0                  0              2                                   
04.01.2000    0                  0              2                                   
05.01.2000    0                  0              2                                   
06.01.2000    23000              1              2                                  
07.01.2000    1000               1              2                                  
08.01.2000    0                  0              2                                   
09.01.2000    0                  0              2                                  
..
..
..
30.01.2000    0                  0              0                                   
31.01.2000     0                 1              3                                   
01.02.2000     0                 1              3                                  
02.02.2000    2500               1              3
```

working day indicates there earnings present on that particular day. I am trying to generate last three column from the date.

**length_week :** gives number of working days in that week

**first_working_day_of_week** : 1 if its first working day of a week

**last_working_day_of_week** : 1 if its last working day of a week

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why did the question change? It might be a better idea to edit the question to the old format. It was a good question plus I also solved the old one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I first changed the format of your `date` column as `pd.to_datetime` couldn't infer the right date format:

```
df.Date.str.replace('.', '-', regex=True)
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

Then use `isocalendar` so that we can work with weeks and days more easily:

```
df[['year', 'week', 'weekday']] = df.Date.dt.isocalendar()
```

Now `length_week` is just the sum of `workingdays` for each seperate weeks:

```
df['length_week'] = df.groupby(['year', 'week']).workingday.transform('sum')
```

and we can get `frst_worday_week` with `idxmax`:

```
min_indexes = df.groupby(['year', 'week'], as_index=False).workingday.transform('idxmax')
df['frst_worday_week'] = np.where(df.index == min_indexes.workingday, 1, 0)
```

Lastly, `last_workdayweek` is similar but a bit tricky. We need the last occurence of `idxmax`, so we will reverse each week inside `groupby`:

```
max_indexes = df.groupby(['year', 'week'], as_index=False).\
                        workingday.transform(lambda x: x[::-1].idxmax()) 
df['last_workdayweek'] = np.where(df.index == max_indexes.workingday, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Hey Nuri. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your time and effort. I will edit back the question now. similar question was answered already so I did not want negative reputation

Comment: Also, I want to extract month_week column (1,2,3,4,5..1,2,3,4..and so on) groupby with month and week didnt help. Can you also add that code if possible